# Comparing categories of ranked variables

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, boruta

I have three categories (patient factors, surgeon factors, and surgery factors). The goal is to see which category can predict an outcome such as infection.

Each category is made up of 8-12 binary variables.

Any suggestions on how to reach this study goal?

I initially wanted to rank the factors within each category and then try to determine which category has the greatest predictive abilities on a binary outcome.

Is there a way to do this? My thoughts were to use Boruta to rank the variables within each category. But then I'm unsure how to either use those ranks to compare categories, or even create a variable from data that would show the ranked variables within each category if some subjects have multiple factors within each category. However, ranking may not be appropriate.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "influence"?  Presumably the factors within a category vary and in most models more variation within a category is associated with more variation in the outcome's probability. That suggests various different senses of "influence:" one related to amount of variation among a category's factors, another related to how strongly that variation is associated with outcome probability, and yet another related to how precisely that degree of association has been estimated.  And what role, if any, do you conceive of any ranking playing here?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am hoping to determine the predictive capabilities of each category on an outcome probability. From there, I wanted to rank binary variables within each category on level of importance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to perform some sort of cross-validation, then.  The role of ranking, though, remains unclear.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.